# Simplify sql query to obtain one line per id

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I have a multi-table SQL query.

My need is: The query should I generate a single line by 'etablissement_id' ... and all information that I want to be back in the same query.

The problem is that this query is currently on a table where "establishment" may have "multiple photos" and suddenly, my query I currently generates several lines for the same id...

I want the following statement - `LEFT JOIN`etablissementContenuMultimedia`ON etablissement.etablissement_id = etablissementContenuMultimedia.etablissementContenuMultimedia_etablissementId` - only a single multimedia content is displayed. Is it possible to do this in the query below?

Here is the generated query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `etablissement`. * , `etablissementContenuMultimedia`. * , `misEnAvant`. * , `quartier`. *
FROM `etablissement`
LEFT JOIN `etablissementContenuMultimedia` ON etablissement.etablissement_id = etablissementContenuMultimedia.etablissementContenuMultimedia_etablissementId
LEFT JOIN `misEnAvant` ON misEnAvant.misEnAvant_etablissementId = etablissement.etablissement_id
LEFT JOIN `quartier` ON quartier_id = etablissement_quartierId
WHERE (
    misEnAvant_typeMisEnAvantId =1
    AND (
        misEnAvant_dateDebut <= CURRENT_DATE
        AND CURRENT_DATE <= misEnAvant_dateFin
    )
)
AND (
    etablissement_isActive =1
)
ORDER BY `etablissement`.`etablissement_id` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here is the code used ZF

```
public function find (){
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $oSelect = $db->select();
    $oSelect->distinct()
            ->from('etablissement')
            ->joinLeft('etablissementContenuMultimedia', 'etablissement.etablissement_id = etablissementContenuMultimedia.etablissementContenuMultimedia_etablissementId')
            ->joinLeft('misEnAvant', 'misEnAvant.misEnAvant_etablissementId = etablissement.etablissement_id')
            ->joinLeft('quartier', 'quartier_id = etablissement_quartierId ')
            ->where ('misEnAvant_typeMisEnAvantId = 1 AND (misEnAvant_dateDebut <= CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE <= misEnAvant_dateFin) ')
            ->where ('etablissement_isActive = 1')
            ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));


    $zSql = $oSelect->__toString();

    if(isset($_GET['debug']) AND $_GET['debug'] == 1)
        echo $zSql ;
    //die();

    $oResultEtablissement = $db->fetchAll($oSelect);   

    return $oResultEtablissement ;
}
```

Can you help me?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the time to redo the whole model of the database ... and now it works. There was no solution for a system as flawed

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have only one of the media displayed out of many regardless of which it may be then you can just add  a limit to the query? After that you can tweak the query for ASCending or DESCending perhaps?

Is this query supposed to have images (or image as it were) for one establishment, or one image each for each active establishment? I see you have a limit 0,30 which means you're likely paginating....

If the result you want is a search for only one establishment, and the first image it comes to would work fine .. just use "limit 1" and you'll only get one result.

Comment: If I have 60 establishment, I need 60 rows. Currently, I put a limit break problem. Indeed, as I sometimes 7 or 8 lines for a single institution, and as I use a "Rand", it is possible that in the first 5 results, I have 3 times the same establishment ... And that is not good.

This request is intended to m'afficher randomly on my home page 5 institutions. And I would find a way to make a good application, rather than through a deduplication in php.